# Selecting First and Last record from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hql

I am using the following queries to find first as well as last inserted records from a table

```
SELECT TOP (1) titlenumber 
FROM cataloguebase

SELECT TOP(1) titlenumber 
FROM cataloguebase
ORDER BY titlenumber DESC;
```

but how can I get first and last record using single query? At list is possible using HQL query?

Comment: Not an answer to your question - but please note that first query has absolutely no guarantee to return same `titlenumber` every time. There is no default ordering and if you do not specify `ORDER BY` you are not guaranteed the order of results - and what TOP 1 will be.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `MAX` and `MIN`:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(titlenumber) AS MaxTitleNumber, 
  MIN(titlenumber) AS MinTitleNumber
FROM cataloguebase
```

Comment: @user2617574 - I don't know about hql, but I think it will be easy to write it in hql this way.